# E-shop creation from scratch

Tags: web

I want to get familiar with web development, so I decided to create an e-shop website, just for practice. Are there any guidelines on how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Oh there's a log way to go.

First you'll need to learn some html and css. In my opinion http://www.w3schools.com/ it's a good site to get started but there are many other good tutorials out there.

Then javascript it would be the next step, trying to set some events etc. You can find some help at w3schools or here www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

Then you surely need to learn php, manage a database and so on. You can also learn that in the sites I already put the link to.

Good luck and have fun.